# Add value to object from array and not become undefined when array runs out

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a function with params and I am doing a forEach loop to add all the values from the loop.

```
const data = (sd) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({
            ['name']: k,
            ['data']: g.map(entry => entry[sd]),
            ['type']: sd
        }));
```

I then push them into a giant array:

```
let arr = ['abc', 'xyz'];
let x = [];
arr.forEach(y => {
  x = [...x, ...data(y)];
});
```

I also want to add another key-value pair to `data`. I want the value to come from an array:

`color_array = ['red', 'blue', 'green']`

So I did:

```
const data = (sd) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({
            ['name']: k,
            ['data']: g.map(entry => entry[sd]),
            ['type']: sd,
            ['color']: color_arr[i++]
        }));
```

Output:

```
color: "red"
data: (3) [1, 2, 3]
name: "Jim"
type: "Manager"

color: "blue"
data: (3) [1, 2, 3]
name: "Steve"
type: "Manager"

color: "green"
data: (3) [1, 2, 3]
name: "John"
type: "Manager"
--------------------NEW SET----------------
color: undefined
data: (3) [1, 2, 3]
name: "John"
type: "CEO"

color: undefined
data: (3) [1, 2, 3]
name: "John"
type: "COO"
```

When I do this, since I only have 5 elements in my array, the rest of the values go `undefined`. Is there any way for me to add elements from the array to start from the beginning of the color_arr?

I mean, for every `x = [...x, ...data(y)];`, Can the colors being added to data(y), always start from `red`, rather than just be valued as undefined?

Comment: why not take `name` instead of a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) with a string of `['name']`? do you have an example of input an wanted output?

Comment: @NinaScholz, I am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the values in the color array by using the modulo. That is, the remainder of dividing your counter by the color array's length.

```js
const color_array = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white'];
let i = 0;
for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
   console.log(color_array[i++ % color_array.length]);
}
```

Untested version of your code:

```
const data = (sd) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({
        ['name']: k,
        ['data']: g.map(entry => entry[sd]),
        ['type']: sd,
        ['color']: color_array[i++ % color_array.length]
}));
```

More information on the `%` operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder

Comment: Is there any way to restart the array with every `x = [...x, ...data(y)];`. So every time `data(y)` is pushed, Can the values from color array being added start from the beginning?

Comment: You can reset `i = 0` inside your loop.

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: You can define the variable `i` above your loop instead and set it to zero for each `y`. For example: `let i; arr.forEach(y => { i = 0;  x = [...x, ...data(y)]; });`